# After upload image on S3 I get invalid url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog, fog-aws

After upload image on S3 I get invalid url.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com//uploads/...
```

My Carrierwave settings

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => "#{ENV['ACCESS_KEY']}",
      :aws_secret_access_key  => "#{ENV['SECRET_KEY']}",
      :region                 => "#{ENV['REGION']}"
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "#{ENV['BUCKET']}"
end
```

This error only production. In development I get valid URL. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

in the _uploader.rb, check this:

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/..."
end
```

Not this:

```
def store_dir
    "/uploads/..."
end
```

Watch out for the extra / before uploads.

Comment: can you give url examples of both environments?

Comment: My .env file is in the folder shared. The application does not see it from there, if you move the file to the root then everything is fine. There is one problem, how to configure that the file is not deleted when deploy via capistrano ?

Comment: That means the problem is in the capistrano recipe, right?

Comment: Just to be sure, you added thoses file in the `:linked_files` in the `deploy.rb`, right?

Comment: Yes, I made this, now all working. Thank you very much.